# DataGridView DefaultCellFormat not working for new values

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview column that hold decimal values, I want to format it with 2 decimal places

```
myColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
```

this works when loading data into DataSource but when I add new values it does not. 
I have to do this manually in CellEndEdit event:

```
var result = int.TryParse(dataGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(), out test);
if (result)
{
  dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = test.ToString("N2");
}
```

can I do this in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `ValueType` property for the column, then you'll get the proper formatting.  Note this property is set in code and not exposed in the designer.

```
dataGrid.Columns[0].ValueType = typeof(decimal);
```

Watch out for exceptions though - if the user enters character data into a cell that is expecting numeric data, an exception is thrown.  Subscribe to the `DataError` event to handle that.